# How to get the select element by option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to get the whole select element by option value using jquery but not getting it. The id of the select element is dynamic and not loaded yet. So I can't use id to get the select element. Therefore trying to get using option value.

Here is the example of select element that I am trying to get:-

```
<select sf-field-model="" id="{{form.formId}}_{{interp(form.formTabId,{'$index':$index, value: item}) || $index}}" ng-disabled="form.readonly" sf-changed="form" class="form-control input-sm c" schema-validate="form" ng-options="item.value as item.name group by item.group for item in form.titleMap" name="_value" ng-model="item['_value']">
   <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
   <option label="TEST-1" value="string:TEST1">TEST-1</option>
   <option label="TEST-2" value="string:TEST2">TEST-2</option>
   <option label="TEST-3" value="string:TEST3">TEST-3</option>
   <option label="TEST-4" value="string:TEST4">TEST-4</option>
   <option label="TEST-5" value="string:TEST5">TEST-5</option>
</select>
```

I tried the following:-

```
var testSelectorText = "select['option[value='?']']";
angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(testSelectorText));
```

Comment: why jquery tag?

Comment: That's not a valid css selector

Comment: I don't think you can select parent using its child yet.

Comment: Use the name "_value" instead of the id? Or is that name shared by multiple selects? You also know the form id. So you could maybe use a selector looking for a select whose id starts with the form id and tab id.

Comment: did you tried `var testSelectorText = "select[name='_value'];` ?

Comment: @Shilly- I can't use name attribute as it is common in other selectors.

Comment: You can select form by id, eg var form = document.getElementById("form"), then just on change output form.value. Or since you are using angularjs you should me able to get value from ng-model ( item['_value']).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to find the select by an `options` value, then try the following:

```
$("select option[value='string:TEST3']").parent();
```

**demo**

```js
var testSelectorText = $("select option[value='string:TEST3']").parent();
console.log(testSelectorText.attr("id"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select sf-field-model="" id="{{form.formId}}_{{interp(form.formTabId,{'$index':$index, value: item}) || $index}}" ng-disabled="form.readonly" sf-changed="form" class="form-control input-sm c" schema-validate="form" ng-options="item.value as item.name group by item.group for item in form.titleMap" name="_value" ng-model="item['_value']">
   <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
   <option label="TEST-1" value="string:TEST1">TEST-1</option>
   <option label="TEST-2" value="string:TEST2">TEST-2</option>
   <option label="TEST-3" value="string:TEST3">TEST-3</option>
   <option label="TEST-4" value="string:TEST4">TEST-4</option>
   <option label="TEST-5" value="string:TEST5">TEST-5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This line uses jquery to find the select element you want, using an `option` `value` to identify it.

```
sel = $("select option[value='string:TEST2']").closest("select");
```

Let me know if this isn't what you wanted.

---

## Demo

```js
// Find the option with known value
// Find the closest 'select'
sel = $("select option[value='string:TEST2']").closest("select");

// Print name to demonstrate we found the item
console.log(sel.attr("name"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select sf-field-model="" id="{{form.formId}}_{{interp(form.formTabId,{'$index':$index, value: item}) || $index}}" ng-disabled="form.readonly" sf-changed="form" class="form-control input-sm c" schema-validate="form" ng-options="item.value as item.name group by item.group for item in form.titleMap" name="_value" ng-model="item['_value']">
   <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
   <option label="TEST-1" value="string:TEST1">TEST-1</option>
   <option label="TEST-2" value="string:TEST2">TEST-2</option>
   <option label="TEST-3" value="string:TEST3">TEST-3</option>
   <option label="TEST-4" value="string:TEST4">TEST-4</option>
   <option label="TEST-5" value="string:TEST5">TEST-5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used recently to do exactly that.

```
$('option[value="string:TEST1"]').closest('select')
```

Answer (score 0):

set `class` to select

```
<select class='myClass' sf-field-model="" id="{{form.formId}}_{{interp(form.formTabId,{'$index':$index, value: item}) || $index}}" ng-disabled="form.readonly" sf-changed="form" class="form-control input-sm c" schema-validate="form" ng-options="item.value as item.name group by item.group for item in form.titleMap" name="_value" ng-model="item['_value']">
   <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
   <option label="TEST-1" value="string:TEST1">TEST-1</option>
   <option label="TEST-2" value="string:TEST2">TEST-2</option>
   <option label="TEST-3" value="string:TEST3">TEST-3</option>
   <option label="TEST-4" value="string:TEST4">TEST-4</option>
   <option label="TEST-5" value="string:TEST5">TEST-5</option>
</select>
<button onclick="callMe()">get Value</button>
```

wirte script as Below

```
function callMe()
{
    var value = $("select.myClass").val();
    console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: Niravdas I don't believe that the OP is trying to get the selected value, he states, `I'm trying to get the whole select element by option value`